# Using Kovenant from Kotlin I keep getting into repetitive code using Deferred

Tags: kotlin, kovenant

When using Kovenant from Kotlin, I end up with a lot of code that is the pattern of:

```kotlin
fun foo(): Promise<SomeResultType, Exception> {
    val deferred = deferred<SomeResultType, Exception>()
    try {
        // bunch of work that deferred.resolve() or deferred.reject()
    }
    catch (ex: Exception) {
       deferred.reject(ex)
    }
    return deferred.promise
}
```

I know I can use `task { ... }` for an async promise and that will take care of some of this, but when I am already async or writing adapters to other async classes I want to use a `Deferred` instance.

Is there something like `task { ... }` that makes a deferred instead and takes care of all the extra work?

**Note:** *this question is intentionally written and answered by the author ([Self-Answered Questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)), so that solutions for interesting problems are shared in SO.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the same pattern as the extension function `Lock.withLock()` and `Closeable.use()` do, which is to wrap a lambda with handling that you want and infer types nicely to avoid boilerplate around your [`Deferred`](http://kovenant.komponents.nl/api/core_usage/#deferred) instance.

The function `withDeferred`:

```
fun <T : Any?> withDeferred(codeBlock: Deferred<T, Exception>.() -> Unit): Promise<T, Exception> {
    val deferred = deferred<T, Exception>()
    try {
        deferred.codeBlock()
    }
    catch (ex: Exception) {
        deferred.reject(ex)
    }
    return deferred.promise
}
```

Which can then be used as:

```
fun foo(): Promise<SomeType, Exception> {
    return withDeferred { 
         // bunch of work that calls resolve() or reject()
    }
}
```

However, it isn't as pretty when you chain promises directly.  Problems will arise when you do not have clear types that can be inferred for the generics of your `Deferred` instance.  So chaining these might require generics to be specified at the call site, for example:

```
fun foo(): Promise<SomeType, Exception> {
    return withDeferred<PreviousType> {
         // bunch of work that calls resolve(PreviousType) or reject()
    } bind { previous ->
        withDeferred<SomeType> {
             // bunch of work that calls resolve(SomeType) or reject()
        }
    }
}
```